# trouble updating column with subselect in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I have dups in my mysql database that I can find with this query:

```
select checksum, count(*) c from MY_DATA group by checksum having c > 1;
```

I get a list of about 200 dups. What I want to do is update a column in the same table to mark them as dups.

I tried this:

```
update MY_DATA SET DONT_PARSE=1 
  where (select count(*) c from MY_DATA group by checksum having c > 1);
```

I get the error: You can't specify target table 'MY_DATA' for update in FROM clause

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
update my_data d join
       (select checksum, count(*) as cnt
        from MY_DATA
        group by checksum
        having cnt > 1
       ) c
       on d.checksum = c.checksum
    set DONT_PARSE = 1 ;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't allow you to reference the table being updated in a subquery in the `update` (or `delete`).  However, `join` can usually be used to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

your query seems also not correct (seems that the where clause is not complete) so you could use a INNER JOIN on the subquery  that retrieve duplicated

You could try using

```
    update MY_DATA m 
    INNER JOIN (
      select checksum, count(*) c 
      from MY_DATA 
      group by checksum 
      having c > 1
    ) t on t.checksum = m.checksum 
    SET DONT_PARSE=1
```